# LaTeX template for Nature Medicine

Tags: templates, journal-publishing

I've googled around a lot with, but I got no success. I hope I can find here some help.

Is there someone that can share a link to download a LaTeX template for the online journal Nature Medicine?

Answer (score 6):

From the [*Nature Medicine* 'Preparing your Submission' page](https://www.nature.com/nm/for-authors/preparing-your-submission)

> We accept manuscripts in PDF, Word or TeX/LaTeX formats; if you are using TeX/LaTeX, we prefer that you submit compiled PDFs up until the pre-acceptance stage.

and later

> TeX/LaTeX
>
> To submit a TeX/LaTeX file, please use any of the standard class files such as `article.cls`, `revtex.cls` or `amsart.cls`. All textual material should be provided as a single file in default Computer Modern fonts. Please avoid non-standard fonts and packages and remove all personal macros before submitting. For graphics, we recommend `graphicx.sty`. Please use numerical references only for citations, and include the references within the manuscript file itself.  If you wish to use BibTeX, please copy the reference list from the `.bbl` file, paste it into the main manuscript `.tex` file, and delete the associated `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` commands. Before submission, please ensure that the complete `.tex` file compiles successfully on your own system with no errors or warnings. There is no need to spend time visually formatting the manuscript: our style will be imposed automatically when the paper is prepared for publication.

So I'd say, don't bother looking for a *Nature Medicine* template. Finding one and getting it to work is probably just a waste of your time. Just use `\documentclass{article}` and as little 'extra' packages and macros as possible. In particular do not try to format the document to make it look similar to published *Nature Medicine* articles. Journal staff will take care of that.